# Преобразование в формат СМЭВ

Tags: xslt

Запрос:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SendRequest xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService">
 <ServiceCode>smev3GIBDDInfo</ServiceCode>
 <Value Name="TestMessage">true</Value>
 <Item Name="request" xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService">
    <Value Name="lastName">СЕРГЕЕВ</Value> 
    <Value Name="firstName">ИВАН</Value> 
    <Value Name="middleName">НИКОЛАЕВИЧ</Value> 
    <Value Name="birthDate">1972-08-15</Value> 
 </Item>
</SendRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Требуется преобразовать в:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rt:carRegistrationsRequest xmlns:cmn="urn://services-gibdd-ru/carservice/commons/1.0.0" xmlns:rt="urn://services-gibdd-ru/carservice/root/1.0.0"><rt:personCriteria> <cmn:firstName>ИВАН</cmn:firstName><cmn:lastName>СЕРГЕЕВ</cmn:lastName><cmn:middleName>НИКОЛАЕВИЧ</cmn:middleName><cmn:birthDate>1972-08-15</cmn:birthDate></rt:personCriteria></rt:carRegistrationsRequest>
```

Просьба помочь составить шаблон xslt.

Также как сделать этот шаблон xslt универсальным? Чтобы этот шаблон xslt применялся для 2 типов xml? Т.е. как прописать в этом xslt еще одно преобразование, чтобы: 1. описанное выше преобразование применялось только для описанных выше xml. 2. а преобразование №2  применялось только для запросов xml типа 2.

xml типа 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SendRequest xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService">
 <ServiceCode>smev3GIBDDInfo</ServiceCode>
 <Value Name="TestMessage">true</Value>
 <Item Name="request" xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService">
    <Value Name="vin">2F1FK91W7YY819789</Value> 
 </Item>
</SendRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

требуемый формат для xml типа 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rt:carRegistrationsRequest xmlns:cmn="urn://services-gibdd-ru/carservice/commons/1.0.0" xmlns:rt="urn://services-gibdd-ru/carservice/root/1.0.0"><rt:carCriteria><cmn:vin>2F1FK91W7YY81978</cmn:vin></rt:carCriteria></rt:carRegistrationsRequest>
```

---

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Копирует все полностью. 
Здесь дело в пространстве имен... И в том как прописать, что нужно копировать только в отношении части узлов + создать новую структуру узлов + перевести все в новое пространство имен.

Запрос:

```
/*/soapenv:Body/*[local-name() = 'SendRequest']/*[local-name() = 'Item']/*[local-name() = 'Value']
```

Возвращает только последний элемент Value:

```
<Value xmlns="http-//www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService" Name="birthDate">1972-08-15</Value>
```

Запрос:

```
*/soapenv:Body/*[local-name() = 'SendRequest']/*[local-name() = 'Item']/*[local-name() = 'Value']
```

Возвращает все элементы, значения которых в новом xml идентичны значениям в исходном xml:

```
<Value xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService" Name="lastName">ИВАНОВ</Value>
<Value xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService" Name="firstName">СЕРГЕЙ</Value>
<Value xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService" Name="middleName">НИКОЛАЕВИЧ</Value>
<Value xmlns="http://www.netvoxlab.ru/SmevRdcService" Name="birthDate">1972:08:15</Value>
```

Но если применять template к ним, то выдает ошибку.

Как это все объединить в одном универсальном шаблоне xslt?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Также как сделать, чтобы этот шаблон xslt применялся для 2 типов xml? Т.е. как прописать в этом xslt еще одно преобразование, которое будет применяться только для запросов xml такого типа:

Comment: Покажите свою попытку написания кода.

Comment: Кажется я понял причину недопонимания: вероятно вы привыкли к формату форума, где подряд идут сообщения. На SO есть вопрос и есть ответы. Вы пишете в поле ответ, которое предназначено для полноценных ответов на вопросы. Пожалуйста, не используйте его. Если вы хотите добавить что-то в вопрос -- нажмите "править" под вопросом. Этот "ответ", который не ответ, а комментарий я удалю. Также у вас две учётки, что затрудняет модератором объединение ответов -- вот об этом была фраза о дублях учёток.

Answer (score 0):

Вы поступаете неправильно. 
XML, который хочет кушать СМЭВ - это очень хорошо стандартизированный SOAP, который автоматически умеет генерироваться из WSDL-схемы, которую легко можно скачать с сервисов минздрава.

Так что вся генерация СМЭВ сводится к тому, чтобы создать один раз интерфейс SOAP по WSDL, после чего вызывать из него обычные методы.

Попытки что-то колхозить приведут к следующему. Минздрав (ну или кто там этим командует) что-то у себя меняе. Правильные пацаны, и я в том числе, просто перегенерируем свою сторону API, скачав новые WSDL. Вы же отправляетесь переписывать шаблоны.

Comment: ТС пробует что-то спросить [правкой вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/406169)